# "На выставочной площади 3 000 кв. метров" или "на выставочной площади размером 3 000 кв. метров"

Tags: дополнение

Пример предложения:

> По его словам, 793 участника авиасалона разместят свои экспозиции на выставочной площади 36 тысяч квадратных метров.

Не лучше ли будет писать

> По его словам, 793 участника авиасалона разместят свои экспозиции на выставочной площади размером 36 тысяч квадратных метров.

Или

> По его словам, на авиасалоне в этом году будет 793 участника, экспозиции которых разместятся на 36 тысячах квадратных метрах выставочной площади.

---

Я перевожу другой текст про выставку (химпром), но в исходнике такая же конструкция, "**на выставочной площади 3000 кв. метров** будет представлен широкий спектр" и т.п.

Вдруг показалось как-то не очень естественно.. Просто показалось?

И как разобрать эту фразу грамматически? "На выставочной площади" - это, вероятно, дополнение. "3000 кв. метров" - это определение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существительное в первом предложении имеет определение в примыкающей форме, выраженное количественным числительным. Обычно такое существительное определяется формами родительного или винительного падежа с предлогами.

> выплавка порядка миллиарда тонн,театр на пятьсот мест,сад в двадцать десятин,,товар на тысячу рублей экономия в два миллиона рублей.

О вариантах.
Возможна взаимная заменяемость вводящего количественный определитель творительного падежа беспредложного существительных со знач. размера, меры, веса, протяженности, цены и предложно-падежных форм, а в непринужденной, но строго нормированной речи - также и формы именительного падежа в определяющей функции:

> дистанция протяженностью в тысячу метров - дистанция в тысячу метров - дистанция протяженностью тысяча метров - дистанция тысяча метров,скидка размером в двадцать процентов - скидка в двадцать процентов - на двадцать процентов - скидка двадцать процентов, дорога длиной в сто верст - дорога в сто верст - дорога длиною сто верст, карандаш ценой в две копейки - карандаш в две копейки - карандаш ценой две копейки, кухня площадью в семь метров - кухня в семь метров - кухня площадью семь метров - кухня семь метров.

Розенталь пишет, что именительный падеж количественного числительного в функции определения стал нормой в спецлитературе.

В тех случаях, когда в роли количественного определителя выступает слово неколичественного значения, им. п. в роли определяющей формы не употребляется:

> приемник размером в пенал - размером с пенал - приемник с пенал.

Вариативность отсутствует в выражениях типа *дорога длиною в жизнь, диалог продолжительностью в тридцать лет*.